# Is the implementation different for the chartjs-adapter-luxon in CoreUI's wrapper of ChartJS in React?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, core-ui, luxon

For some weeks now, I get `react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught Error: This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided.` when I change my `x-axis` to `type: time`. After reading numerous answers, the closest I get is using a CDN in the HTML header, but that does not seem to work. I am using CoreUI's ChartJS wrapper for React which seems to restrict some of the access I supposedly need to get the adapter working. I keep looking up what a "complete adapter" means for luxon, but I see only ***optional*** parameters in `adapters.date`, not ***required***.

Another route I looked into was the luxon adapter being implemented *before* ChartJS gets called but I don't see any possible async option that would then implement the module once the chart loads.

My current dependencies:

```
"@coreui/chartjs": "^3.0.0",
"@coreui/react-chartjs": "^2.1.0",
 "chartjs-adapter-luxon": "^1.1.0",
 "luxon": "^3.0.1",
```

At this point, I do not know if the issue is CoreUI, React, ChartJS, Luxon, or something else. Is it possible to implement the adapter and if so, how would I do so?

Additional photos:

[image: Starting point of type: time]

[image: chartjs-adapter-luxon is code-split when bundling happens]

[image: Unable to use the adapter currently, I manually set up the date conversions I wanted with Luxon itself]

[image: Error log asking for complete date adapter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing of ChartJS, CoreUI ChartJS, and react-chartjs-2, CoreUI currently does not implement the adapter properly. I do not know why but if a CoreUI user wants a date adapter, react-chartjs-2 is the way to go. There isn't much work to migrate over to react-chartjs-2 except for explicitly registering ChartJS pieces.

Comment: I can confirm that CoreUI v4 is not handling the date adapter stuff correctly for some reason. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a date adapter for the date library you are using, in your case that being a date adapter for luxon

```bash
npm install luxon chartjs-adapter-luxon --save
```

Then you need to import it where you import and make your chart

```js
import 'chartjs-adapter-luxon';
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response, I greatly appreciate it. However, this method has not worked for me; the result is the same as above. Those packages have been installed before asking (but I copied and pasted the npm install that you wrote above) and wrote out the import statement in the file that my chart option object was in. I am curious what else is needed for the luxon adapter. Thank you for this lead though.